# Custom Product Collection not Getting Filtered by Layered Navigation in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento2.4.1

I am trying to create a page that show a list of products that have price which is greater than some specific amount and i also want to add Layered navigation for filter these product collection based upon different attribute. But in Magento 2.4.1 when i implement the code for layered navigation in layout file it not properly work and show a layered navigation.

So Here the specific attribute product list are correctly show on custom page, but when i add layered navigation functionality the custom page are not properly render and Layered navigation not work properly.

[image: Custom Product List Page]

And When i click on Above page generated link it show product page data like this:-

[image: Product page data]

And if we click on any generate data link it redirected to custom product page with already layered navigation applied but not properly worked.

[image: Custom Product page]

[image: My Module File Structure]

**app/code/Test/Special/Block/Navigation  State.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Block\Navigation;
class State extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Test\Special\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data=[])
{
            parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $data);

}
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Block/Product  ListProduct.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Block\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Test\Special\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Block  Link.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Block;
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Block  Navigation.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Block;
class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Test\Special\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $filterList,
            $visibilityFlag);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Controller/Index  Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/etc/frontend  routes.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="special-machine" id="special">
            <module name="Test_Special"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Test/Special/etc  di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Context" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProviderInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateKeyInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\CollectionFilterInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price" type="Test\Special\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Test/Special/etc  module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Special" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Model/Layer  Resolver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Model\Layer;
class Resolver extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
{
    protected $layer;
    protected $layersPool;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Test\Special\Model\Layer $layer,
        array $layersPool
    ) {
        $this->layer = $layer;
        $this->layersPool = $layersPool;
        parent::__construct($objectManager, $layersPool);
    }

    public function create($layerType)
    {
        if (isset($this->layer)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Catalog Layer has been already created');
        }
        if (!isset($this->layersPool[$layerType])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException($layerType . ' does not belong to any registered layer');
        }
        $this->layer = $this->objectManager->create($this->layersPool[$layerType]);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Model/ResourceModel/Layer/Filter  Price.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\DimensionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Test\Special\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $connectionName = null,
        IndexScopeResolverInterface $priceTableResolver = null,
        Context $httpContext = null,
        DimensionFactory $dimensionFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $eventManager, $layerResolver, $session, $storeManager, $connectionName, $priceTableResolver, $httpContext, $dimensionFactory);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/Model  Layer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Special\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );
    }
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
            $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['lt' => 95])
                ->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
            return $productCollection;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/Special/view/frontend/layout  special_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Test\Special\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="layerednavigation_index_index" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
            <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>


    <!--Magento core-->
    <!--<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">-->
        <!--<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">-->
            <!--<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />-->
            <!--<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml">-->
                <!--<arguments>-->
                    <!--<argument name="product_layer_view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\LayeredNavigation\ViewModel\Layer\Filter</argument>-->
                <!--</arguments>-->
            <!--</block>-->
        <!--</block>-->
    <!--</referenceContainer>-->

    <!--Custom layered Navigation-->
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Test\Special\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" as="navigation" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Test\Special\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/state.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
</page>
```

Can anyone please help me to correct the syntax or guide me how to achieve Layered Navigation in custom product collection?